# Registration in app right way

Tags: java, android

I am want to do registration in my app. So i have made all requests to my web service. 
I now when user is registered.

Now i need to save somewhere that he is registered that don't give him registration form again.

How to do this ?

Do i need to save somewhere in my sqlite database and every time when app lunches check if he is registered user. Or maybe in app settings i could save this information.

I am new to developing android app and i am searching for the right way.

Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save that with `SharedPreferences`. Check the link for sample code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref.

This data will be removed if the users uninstalls the app or clears all data from system menu.

Edit: If you really want to remember preferences across installs you should try Backup API. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: I guess, as a user, I would like my account to be cleaned up if I uninstall the app. So backuping doesn't seem very interesting here, even possibly invasive.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use [Android's Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to handle user account. This aproach is the most secure (credentials are not exposed), however it has two drawbacks:

- It's a little bit complocated to set up
- It requires at least API version 5

Answer (score 1):

Once the user registered you can save in your sqlite database and you have to check for each time when your application launches. But if the user uninstalled the application and tried to reinstall it ll ask for registration again.. In order to avoid this you have to store the information like the device id and the registered details in some servers and also in sqlite database and have to check when the application launches...